# Error for patch test

Tags: community-official-site

I had an issue in my project, so I changed some code in one of contribute modules I was using. Once the change was done and it was all okay, my client asked to put it on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/) for their reference and for future help.

I have created the patch from the changes I have done. I applied it to a fresh clone of that module. I got a successful message saying *Patch applied very cleanly*.

When I uploaded the patch to community, It showed *D7 CI error* in test.

I researched about this "D7 CI error", but I didn't find anything.

What does that error mean? How can I fix it?

In https://www.drupal.org/node/1263934/qa, I am getting the same error message, even if I created *ex novo* the patch using a fresh copy of the module files I cloned from the project repository.

Comment: May you provide a link for the issue to which your patch is attached?

Comment: Drupal CI aka testbots. You can find information and FAQ about test failure from: https://www.drupal.org/automated-testing/faq#local

Comment: @kiamlaluno and @ hene Firstly thx for correcting my mistakes. from above link i got bit of idea about Drupal CI testbots. But still not able to get what causing the issue when patch has placed. here is the link. https://www.drupal.org/node/2678076

Comment: Looking at the [console output](https://dispatcher.drupalci.org/job/default/304623/console), I just see two errors: "ERROR: No valid tests were specified" and "ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: None of the test reports contained any result." There isn't anything more specific that explains what is wrong.